# Linq with multiple where clauses not pulling back data

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using VB.NET and Linq; I have two separate conditions that have to be satisfied. When I run them individually they work fine however when I combine them into a single statement with multiple where statements then I get 0 records returned.

If I run the first where clause without the 2nd I get 70 records
If I run the 2nd where clause without the first i get 5 records
When I run with both where clauses I get 0 records returned

Here is the code.

```vb
submissionDetails = (From r In model.NIBRS_ReportStatusByORI
                     Where (sCritera.ORI.Contains(r.OriginatingORI) _
                                And Not r.ReportType = "ZERO REPORT" _
                                And r.OccurrenceDate >= sCritera.BeginDate _
                                And r.OccurrenceDate <= sCritera.EndDate _
                                And (r.ActionCode <> "D"))
                     Where (sCritera.ORI.Contains(r.OriginatingORI) _
                                And r.ReportType.Equals("ZERO REPORT") _
                                And r.YearMonthDate >= sCritera.BeginDate _
                                And r.YearMonthDate <= sCritera.EndDate _
                                And (r.ActionCode <> "D"))
                     Select New ReportStatusDetails() With {
                        .ChangeDate = r.Insertdate,
                        .IncidentId = r.IncidentID,
                        .IncidentIdentifier = r.IncidentIdentifier,
                        .OriginatingORI = r.OriginatingORI,
                        .ReportType = r.ReportType,
                        .StatusID = r.StatusID,
                        .SubmittedBy = r.Username,
                        .ReportDate = r.YearMonthDate,
                        .ReportDateString = r.YearMonth,
                        .OccurrenceDate = r.OccurrenceDate
               }).ToList()
```

Comment: Why do you think the 70 and the 5 must necessarily overlap?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by overlap but i can have some reports that are not zero reports (70) and not have any zero reports at all; i can also have the inverse 5 zero reports and not have any Non-Zero reports; however, when i have both based on the conditions then I want to add then so total would be 70 + 5 or 75 items in my list (i hopw that makes sense)

Comment: What you describe requires "or", instead of "and" (which using Where twice effectively is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
submissionDetails = (From r In model.NIBRS_ReportStatusByORI
                 Where (sCritera.ORI.Contains(r.OriginatingORI) _
                            And Not r.ReportType = "ZERO REPORT" _
                            And r.OccurrenceDate >= sCritera.BeginDate _
                            And r.OccurrenceDate <= sCritera.EndDate _
                            And (r.ActionCode <> "D"))
                 Select New ReportStatusDetails() With {
                    .ChangeDate = r.Insertdate,
                    .IncidentId = r.IncidentID,
                    .IncidentIdentifier = r.IncidentIdentifier,
                    .OriginatingORI = r.OriginatingORI,
                    .ReportType = r.ReportType,
                    .StatusID = r.StatusID,
                    .SubmittedBy = r.Username,
                    .ReportDate = r.YearMonthDate,
                    .ReportDateString = r.YearMonth,
                    .OccurrenceDate = r.OccurrenceDate
           }).Union(From r In model.NIBRS_ReportStatusByORI
                 Where (sCritera.ORI.Contains(r.OriginatingORI) _
                            And r.ReportType.Equals("ZERO REPORT") _
                            And r.YearMonthDate >= sCritera.BeginDate _
                            And r.YearMonthDate <= sCritera.EndDate _
                            And (r.ActionCode <> "D"))
                 Select New ReportStatusDetails() With {
                    .ChangeDate = r.Insertdate,
                    .IncidentId = r.IncidentID,
                    .IncidentIdentifier = r.IncidentIdentifier,
                    .OriginatingORI = r.OriginatingORI,
                    .ReportType = r.ReportType,
                    .StatusID = r.StatusID,
                    .SubmittedBy = r.Username,
                    .ReportDate = r.YearMonthDate,
                    .ReportDateString = r.YearMonth,
                    .OccurrenceDate = r.OccurrenceDate
           }).ToList()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).